# How do I show that $F(1/x) = -F(x)$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $F$ be defined by

$F(x) = \int_1^x \frac{\exp(\frac{u^2 + 1}{u})du}{u}$.

I'm supposed to show that $F(1/x) = -F(x)$. The hint in the back of my book says that I should use the substitution $v = \frac{1}{u}$. When I do this I get the integral

$\int_1^x \frac{-1}{v^2}\exp(\frac{1}{v} + v)dv$. Am I supposed to proceed by doing integration by parts?

Comment: You need to change your integration limits after making the substitution.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of $F(x)$ is
$$F(x)=\int_1^x e^{u+1/u}\frac{du}{u}$$
Substituting $u\mapsto 1/v$ sends $e^{u+1/u}\mapsto e^{v+1/v}$ and $du/u\mapsto-dv/v$, and replaces your integration bounds with $1$ and $1/x$ respectively, so you have
$$F(x)=\int_1^{1/x} e^{v+1/v}\cdot -\frac{dv}{v}=-F(1/x)$$
and you are done.

Comment: I just want to make sure that the order of the bounds doesn't matter. So even if $1/x < 1$, we can still write the integral as you've done above?

Comment: @K.M Yes! Recall the following property of integrals:
$$\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$$

Answer (score 2):

If you do $v=\dfrac1u$ and $\mathrm dv=-\dfrac{\mathrm du}{u^2}$, then your integral becomes$$-\int_1^{\frac1x}\frac{\exp\left(\frac1v+v\right)}{\frac1v}\times\frac1{v^2}\,\mathrm dv=-\int_1^{\frac1x}\frac{\exp\left(\frac1v+v\right)}v\,\mathrm dv=-F\left(\frac1x\right).$$